# Xcode 4.5.2 libc++ std::bad_cast when implementing custom (string)stream

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm having problems implementing my own custom stringbuf and stringstream using char16_t as char type. As test I used a nullstringbuf and nullstringstream that I found in an old, and maybe out dated C++ manual. This nullstringstream acts as "/dev/null" and is a simple implementation. 
This simple nullstream is working when I use `<char>` but fails with an std::bad_cast exception when I use `<char16_t>`. I know that there must be a `char_traits<char16_t>` available but libc++ seems to have it present.

```
     class nullstringbuf : public std::basic_stringbuf<char16_t>
     {
     public:
        nullstringbuf( )
        {
           setp(0,0);
           setg(0,0,0);
        }


        virtual ~nullstringbuf()
        {

        }

        virtual int_type underflow()
        {
           setg(0,0,0);
           return traits_type::eof();
        }


        virtual int overflow(int c)
        {
           setp(0,0);
           if ( c==traits_type::eof() )
              return 0;

           return c;
        }


     };



     class nullstringstream : virtual public std::basic_stringstream<char16_t>
     {
     public:
        // Constructor(s)
        nullstringstream(std::ios_base::openmode om = std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in)
        : std::basic_stringstream<char16_t>(om)
        {
           init(&m_StreamBuf);
        }

        nullstringstream(base::xstring const& val, std::ios_base::openmode om = std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::in)
        : std::basic_stringstream<char16_t>(val, om)
        {
           init(&m_StreamBuf);
        }

        // Destructor
        virtual ~nullstringstream()
        {

        }


        nullstringbuf* rdbuf()
        {
           return &m_StreamBuf;
        }

        std::basic_string<char16_t> str() const
        {
           return m_StreamBuf.str();
        }

     private:
        nullstringbuf           m_StreamBuf;

        nullstringstream(nullstringstream const &); // do NOT implement!
        nullstringstream& operator=(nullstringstream const &); // do NOT implement!
     };
```

To get it compiled I also needed to specialize `std::ctype<char16_t>`.

**My questions?:**

- Do I need to implement or specialize, besides
  std::ctype/std::basic_stringbuf/std::basic_stringstream, any more
  classes or templates?
- Has anybody else the same problems using
  libc++, char16_t and iostreams?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiating the IOStreams with a not readily supported stream type requires more than just instantiating it and providing `std::char_traits<cT>`. At the very least you also need to instantiate a number of facets:

- `std::ctype<cT>` gets accessed although not necessarily used in many contexts.
- `std::numpunct<cT>` gets used when formatting or parsing any numeric type.
- `std::num_get<cT>` is needed when parsing sny numeric type.
- `std::num_put<cT>` is beeded when formatting any numeric type.
- If you were to use file streams you'd also need to provide `std::codecvt<cT, char>`.

Off-hand I think these are the facets you need. However, I remember that there were more thing I needed to do to set up my streams than I thought would be necessary.